# PrefPanes & Plist Save Location in 10.7

Tags: osx-lion, xcode, file-handling, plist

I'm writing a preference pane & this prefpane saves a plist file with settings & I used to store this in the /Library/Preferences/ folder; This worked fine in OS X 10.6 but now we switched to 10.7 & apples has revoked the rights to write in the /Library/Preferences folder (without an administrator password) i.e. the prefpane can't write there. Is there a better location that is accessible by all the system where I can save my prefpane's plist file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably not explicitly write to `Library/Preferences`, but instead use `NSUserDefaults`. If that's not enough for you, I believe `~/Library/Application Support` is an allowable option.